# How to turn on software radio switch on eMachines e525 notebook with Intel WiFi Link 5150

Tags: windows-7, wifi-driver

The eMachines e525 notebook with `Intel WiFi Link 5150` has `Windows 7` installed with all available updates and latest Intel drivers for its WiFi adapter.

The system looks fine, no problems shown in logs, no exclamation marks in device manager, e.t.c.

However, the networks search detects no networks. The `Intel WiFi Manual Diagnostic Tool` reports that the `software radio switch` is `off`. I found in some sources that Intel driver ususally accompanied (at least used to be) with the system tray icon that allows to control the software switch.

For some reason this tray app is not set to run by the driver installer despite of the executable is intsalled (actually it is used by the diagnostic tool as well). If I try to start it manually by the command I found on the Internet, the tray icon shorlty appears in the tray but then the app terminates with no messages (I assume it is discontinued for Win7+ as references I found are in regard of XP)

The same notebook being booted with Fedora Live CD perfectly detects a number of networks around. So, the problem definitely lays in the sofware/settings.

The question is how to turn this software switch on or fix the possible problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by removing the Intel's latest driver and installing the driver recommended by the Acer's e525 support page.

This solution inspired by the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/525404/160754) to a similar question in regard of Windows 8 with the similar problem